# non-homogeneous Recurrence Relation for f(x) = n^2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

Im having some trouble with a non-homogeneous Recurrence Relation. My question is:

$u_{n} - 5u_{n-1} + 4u_{n-2} = n^2$

My working out so far:

**$r^{2}-5r+4r = 0$ = (r-1)(r-4)**

Giving the roots 1 and 4 so my homogeneous equation is:

**(λ + 4β)**

My issue is that I'm not sure how to guess the non-homogeneous particular, I've read if it equals $n^2$ the guess should be of the form 
$A_{2}n^{2} + A_{1}n + A_{0}$ but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess $$u_n=a + bn+c n^2+d n^3$$ and replace in $$u_{n} - 5u_{n-1} + 4u_{n-2} -n^2=0$$ You should arrive to something like $$(-3 b-27 d+11c)+ (33 d-6 c)n-(9 d+1) n^2=0$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Oh man, that is not what i was expecting haha

But thank you :^)

Comment: @reemq8. You are welcome ! $u_n$ must be of a degree higher than in the rhs. You could show the same assuming $u_n=a + bn+c n^2+d n^3+en^4$ and conclude that $e=0$. Cheers.

Comment: Okay so, if i get it in the form if i combine the particular with the homogeneous equation  (which i think is correct)

$(λ^n + 4β^n) +67/27n + 11/9n^2 + 2/9n^3 $

do i then sub in some values, like:

 $a_{0} = 0 / a_{1} = 2$ ?

Comment: @reemq8. Your formula does not seem to be correct : look at the coefficient of $n^2$; it tells that $d=-\frac 19$. And for the homogeneous part $c_1+c_2 4^n$.

Comment: Oh maybe I'm misunderstanding how you calculate a b c d then, can you explain that a bit further? i thought you set it to equal n^2 and factored everything out till you got a b c d.

Comment: Say that all coefficients are $0$. Solve for $b,c,d$ and absorb $a$ in $c_1$

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense, so if I'm correct in what i assume the next steps are:


Step 1: **B = -67/54 C = -11/18 D = -1/9**, Sub that into the guess for $a_{n} = -67/54(n) -11/18(n)^2 -1/9(n)^3$

Step 2: Add that equation onto the homogeneous equation

step 3: work out $c_{1} c_{2}$